# So what exactly does <FILE> do?

Tags: perl

So, I've used `<FILE>` a large number of times. A simple example would be:

```
open (FILE, '<', "someFile.txt");
while (my $line = <FILE>){
print $line;
}
```

So, I had thought that using `<FILE>` would take a a part of a file at a time (a line specifically) and use it, and when it was called on again, it would go to the next line. And indeed, whenever I set `<FILE>` to a scalar, that's exactly what it would do. But, when I told the computer a line like this one:

```
print <FILE>;
```

it printed the entire file, newlines and all. So my question is, what does the computer think when it's passed `<FILE>`, exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Diamond operator `<>` used to read from file is actually built-in `readline` function.

From [`perldoc -f readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)

> Reads from the filehandle whose typeglob is contained in EXPR (or from *ARGV if EXPR is not provided). In **scalar context**, each call reads and returns the next line until end-of-file is reached, whereupon the subsequent call returns undef. In **list context**, reads until end-of-file is reached and returns a list of lines.

If you would like to check particular context in perl,

```
sub context { return wantarray ? "LIST" : "SCALAR" }

print my $line  = context(), "\n";
print my @array = context(), "\n";
print context(), "\n";
```

output

```
SCALAR
LIST
LIST
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends if it's used in a scalar context or a list context.

In scalar context: `my $line = <file>` it reads one line at a tie.
In list context: `my @lines = <FILE>` it reads the whole file.

When you say `print <FILE>;` it's list context.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is different depending on what context it is being evaluated in:

```
my $scalar = <FILE>; # Read one line from FILE into $scalar
my @array = <FILE>; # Read all lines from FILE into @array
```

As [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) takes a list argument, `<FILE>` is evaluated in list context and behaves in the latter way.